# Calendar with Outlook like functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to do the following for managing appointments.

When the user opens the app, show him a calendar control which will fetch his schedule from the sql server database. If the user is scheduled to meet Mr. A,X and Z on 15th, then the calendar control should display three links in that calendar for that particular day. Clicking on these links will take the user to the details of the person he is supposed to meet. Similarly do for other dates too.

I can use ASP.NET, AJAX, jQuery anything. Are you aware of any existing project or code that exists for the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a fully existing project you will not find no,
but you can however use jquery and its vast plugin database for some of your front end functionalities.

however this would just be a small help, as you would still need to do many manual coding,
this just shows a calendar with data. if you provide the data of course.
all server side code would still be your work and possibly the custom front end stuff too, login system, clicking the link opening the calendar on the right spot. etc etc.

if you are interested in doing it this way,
here is a hand full of calendar plugins you could use

- [ical calendars](http://stefanoverna.com/blog/2009/01/create-astonishing-ical-like-calendars-with-jquery.html)
- [Plans](http://www.planscalendar.com/index.php?p=features)
- [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/)

these are just a few, you can find many more on the net

if you choose not to take this path, there are probably serverside controls you could use,
like [telerik's rad Calendar](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/calendar.aspx), of course this option comes with a price. i have no knowledge of free alternatives (and defenately not whether those are as flexible as previously mentioned solutions)

Comment: To add to the above, there is also a JavaScript plugin that I've recently used. It generates .ics files, which are a standard compliant calendar file-type. It doesn't work for older versions of IE, but you can dissect the code really easily. **[ics.js](https://github.com/nwcell/ics.js)**

Answer (score 0):

telerik.com  RadScheduler.  I use it alot and its pretty good an flexible.  You can do your links scenario with either their Appointment Template or the new jQuery templates.